# How to fetch BLOB type data from database in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a `BLOB` datatype column in table `referral_documents` and my query is

```
$query = "select content from referral_documents where id ='1'";
$stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$attachmentData = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

It cannot return any content data.

Comment: You will end up with a php resource for content. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#blob

Comment: Try with stream_get_contents($attachmentData)

Answer (score 0):

Does the script run in mysql workbench?

Also, when I worked with drupal 8 i ran into a problem with the PDO drivers. They where overwritten.

Try setting up your own connection to the database http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php and running the script like that.

Also, if you just want 1 content from referral documents try. `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0)`

`fetch` grabs the next row, while `(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0)` fetches the first column. So it will come back with your data without extra overhead of putting it into an array.